# Using multiple Python kernels in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to start using Visual Studio Code with Python/Jupyter extensions by Don Jayamanne. I have both Python 3.5 and 3.6 kernels on my system, but I am unable to make them both visible to those extensions. Only the system default kernel is available in VS Code.

How to make sure VS Code and Python extensions see all available Python kernels and allow me to choose from them?

Answer (score 12):

I am using Microsoft's Python extension.
For this, you can do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Command palette) -> `Python: Select Interpreter`

OR, click on the environment on the bottom left corner (e.g. below), and change it.

[image]

If it is still not discoverable, then we need to include the relevant paths. You can do so via the `Command Palette` -> `Preferences: Open User Settings` -> Search for `path` -> Select the `Python` extension to change its settings -> Point the paths to your system setup accordingly (e.g. `Conda Path`, `Pipenv Path`, `Python Path`, `Venv Path`)

Answer (score 3):

I got it.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Command palette) -> Python: Select Workspace interpreter