# Getting an error while using pipenv install command for my project on mac

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I have a python project downloaded from github. This project works fine on my friend's system (windows).

Python Version 3.10.8.

I am trying to use the same and trying to install the required packages by running `pipenv install`.

Once I run `pipenv install` I am getting a large error message which is basically -

**1. A list of messages like the following (but with something other than anyio)**

`An error occurred while installing anyio==3.6.1 ; python_full_version >= '3.6.2' --hash=sha256:cb29b9c70620506a9a8f87a309591713446953302d7d995344d0d7c6c0c9a7be --hash=sha256:413adf95f93886e442aea925f3ee43baa5a765a64a0f52c6081894f9992fdd0b! Will try again.`

**2. Near the end of the error message the following snippet:**

```
 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [16 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       Traceback (most recent call last):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         File "/private/var/folders/v6/xmvqfwjd6pl63vc6fdk6sn880000gn/T/pip-install-i2_46x3i/mysqlclient_1dc68b0313c14eec82d2c3d19c6f8169/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:           metadata, options = get_config()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         File "/private/var/folders/v6/xmvqfwjd6pl63vc6fdk6sn880000gn/T/pip-install-i2_46x3i/mysqlclient_1dc68b0313c14eec82d2c3d19c6f8169/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:           libs = mysql_config("libs")
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         File "/private/var/folders/v6/xmvqfwjd6pl63vc6fdk6sn880000gn/T/pip-install-i2_46x3i/mysqlclient_1dc68b0313c14eec82d2c3d19c6f8169/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:           raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       OSError: mysql_config not found
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       mysql_config --version
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       mariadb_config --version
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       mysql_config --libs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
```

I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling python using different installation methods
- Upgrading pip, pipenv
- Removing Setup tools
- Removing the virtualenv using `pipenv --rm`

But the problem persists. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved after -

1. Removing all traces of old python installations via homebrew and python.org package
2. Removing symlinks of anything related to python or pip. To find all symlinks, I ran `find . -type l -ls` in the root (~) directory. At this point,

   - `which python3` returns `/usr/local/bin/python3`
   - `which python` returns not found
   - `which pip3` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip3`
   - `which pip` returns not found
3. Running `brew install mysql` in terminal
4. Running `brew install mysql-client`  in terminal
5. Adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` to `/.zshrc`
6. Installing python via python.org package
7. Running the "Install Certificates.command" executable which was inside the latest python installation. At this point,

   - `which python3` returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3`
   - `which python` returns not found
   - `which pip3` returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3`
   - `which pip` returns not found
8. Adding `alias python="python3"` in .zshrc
9. Adding `alias pip="python3 -m pip"` in .zshrc
10. Running pip install -U pip
11. Running pip install pipenv
12. Opening the project directory in github
13. Selecting .venv as the kernel ([help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109867/using-multiple-python-kernels-in-visual-studio-code))
14. Running `pipenv install` in the project directory.